# Can 64-bit DIFXAPP run from "Program Files (x86)"?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, device-driver

I have a 32-bit application which also has a device driver. I am using the DIFXAPP support in WiX to install the driver. Is it OK on 64-bit windows  to install the application and 64-bit driver files to a subdirectory of `Program Files (x86)` then have DIFX install the driver to the driver store from there? I believe that it's not allowed to run 64-bit code from the 32-bit Program Files directory but in this case I'm not running it, just asking DIFXAPP to copy it. The actual function used is `DriverPackageInstall()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a convention to install programs 32-bit programs into the x86 tree, but it is not forbidden. It is legal to copy the DIFXAPP executable and accompanying files into a sub-directory in `Program Files (x86)` and start it from there.

Comment: Thanks Christopher - have you a reference for that? By the way with the WiX difx extension I don't explicitly copy the DIFXAPP executable(s) anywhere, that's taken care of and I don't know where WiX puts them!